# The Properties-area text is smaller than the others

Tags: properties

I have encountered a small problem. As you can see from the attached image, the Properties-area text (circled in red) is smaller than the others.
Can this be corrected?

Thank you for your attention

Mirko

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover over the properties area, hold down <kbd>Ctrl-MMB</kbd> and move the mouse up or down in the window.
You can also use <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: You may want to expand the answer with `numpad +` and `numpad -` ?

Comment: Forgot that one! Now added thanks!

Comment: Thanks John
It worked!