# Properties menu only has tiny text which is too small to read

Tags: interface

In Blender, 3.4, upgraded to 3.4.1.

The text in the Properties menu is extremely tiny. The other menus are fine but the Properties menu is too small to read. Adjusting the resolution in the preferences does increase the menu text but not just for the Properties menu alone - it increases the text size for all of the Blender interface.

Is this a bug?

[image: Screenshot of Properties menu showing tiny text]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282705/the-properties-area-text-is-smaller-than-the-others/282709#comment485810_282709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Properties tab is zoomed out. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MMB</kbd> (middle mouse button) to zoom in.

Comment: You can also use + or - on the numpad  if you have one.

Comment: This is awesome. Never knew this existed. I think it had something to do with the imported file. I don't remember changing the window size in this way. But that was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Powersolo This also works in other software as well, browsers for example.